# Increment multidimensional array when form fields are cloned

Tags: jquery

I have a form that allows for a set of form fields to be duplicated (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sd9Ag/8/ ). How would I increment the array number in the name attribute when the inputs are duplicated.

For example:

```
<input type="input" name="question[1]"  />
<input type="input" name="questionURL[1]"  />
<input type="input" name="answer[1][]"  />
<input type="input" name="answerURL[1][]"  />
```

And when it is cloned, increment the array number:

```
<input type="input" name="question[2]"  />
<input type="input" name="questionURL[2]"  />
<input type="input" name="answer[2][]"  />
<input type="input" name="answerURL[2][]"  />
```

The reason I need to do this is so that the questions and answers are grouped when the form is submitted.

Comment: Why isn't `question[1][]` just `question[1]`.  It seems like the only repeating items are answers.

Comment: hey Stephen, good point. I will update the question to fix this glaring error.

Comment: Why do you need to use the numbers at all instead of just question[], answer[], etc.?

Comment: When I submit the form, I would like to keep the question and answer groups together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**update**

Ok, i have used your jsfiddle (*which i missed in my first answer*) code and made some alterations.

- the note of the question i renamed to `qnote[1]` to avoid confusion with answer notes
- answers are named as `answer[1][1]` for first answer to first question, `answer[1][2]` for second answer to first question ... `answer[2][1]` for first answer of second question, etc..

working code at http://jsfiddle.net/dcUdU/1/

---

***original answer***

Use the following code

```
   elem.name = elem.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/,function(str,p1){
         return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']';
       });
```

for [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) of the input elements you have cloned (*you need to [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) from the last group of fields*)

It uses a regular expression to find the number inside the `[` and `]` and increment it by one.

***example at*** http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/WZAU6/

reference for [function as parameter to the replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: Thanks Gaby, This does not work with my jsFiddle example, as it clones more than one answer input.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Now I have to study this beauty to figure out what is going on! Thanks, you gave me a whole new set of functions to learn about!

Comment: @siuperUntitled, you are welcome. And if you get stuck anywhere, ask for more info ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/z3SSL/1/

The main change is this:

```
var emptyQ = $("li.question").clone(),
    emptyA = $("li.answer").clone();

emptyQ.html(emptyQ.html()
               .replace("question[" + (nextId - 1), "question[" + nextId)
               .replace("qnotes[" + (nextId - 1), "qnotes[" + nextId));
emptyA.html(emptyA.html()
               .replace("answer[" + (nextId - 1), "answer[" + nextId)
               .replace("anotes[" + (nextId - 1), "anotes[" + nextId));
```

Comment: thanks for the help! the example you provided is not working! the form input sets are no longer duplicating correctly.

Comment: this seems to work better, however if more than one question is cloned, the number is always 2. Is there a way to store the index. Whew! this is a mindbender!

Comment: @superUntitled - you can increment the 'nextId' variable (I didn't). This is just meant to illustrate the technique. E.g. you might want a counter for answers per question - whatever you need to produce the right arrays of params on the server side.